# Jinja2 template render {{variable}} in place of empty string, if variable not set

Tags: python, jinja2

My template contains 2 {{var1}} and {{var2}} placeholders.
If I only set variable for var1: value1, then {{var2}} is also replaced by empty string. But I want {{var2}} instead of empty string

## code snippet:

```
var = {var1:value1}
tmp = Template(f.read(),start="{{",end="}}")
data = tmp.render(var)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a fallback assignment when setting var1 and var2:

```
var1 = value1 if value1 else "{{var1}}"
var2 = value2 if value2 else "{{var2}}"

var = {"var1":var1, "var2":var2}
tmp = Template(f.read(),start="{{",end="}}")
data = tmp.render(var)
```

Or you could do it in your Django template like:

```
{% if var1 %}   
    {{ var1 }}
{% else %}
    {% templatetag openvariable %} var1 {% templatetag closevariable %}
{%endif%}
```

Or, if you're using Jinja2 for templating instead, you could do it in your Jinja2 template like:

```
{% if var1 %}   
    {{ var1 }}
{% else %}
    {% raw %}
    {{ var1 }}
    {% endraw %}
{%endif%}
```

Comment: there can be multiple placeholders in the template. For ease sake, I mentioned 2 placeholders.

Comment: @d3514514 These replies are also simplified. This is the method you should use to solve your problem. You should take that method and find how it best applies to your use case. If you have another specific issue, you should post it as an edit or comment for clarification.  Otherwise, if this addresses your problem, you should select this answer.